# viewWillAppear / viewWillDisappear not called....my answer to this

Tags: iphone

I have been struggling with this issue for a while and i noticed that many people came across the same thing by reading many posts here and on other forums. Just this morning i realised what i was doing wrong and i thought of sharing it just in case someone stumbles over it in the future.

the problem in my implementation was that within viewDidLoad of view controller (VC1) i was setting its view property to a new view controller (VC2) which forces i believe the framework to exit viewDidLoad of VC1 without reaching its end, hence not calling the consequent delegate function of the view controller: viewWillAppear, viewWillDisappear, viewWillAppear, and viewWillDisappear!

So my solution was to delay all the code that has to do with creating and setting VC2 to be called from within viewDidAppear instead of viewDidLoad. If you do it from viewWillAppear you will get to the same trouble.

Hope it helps
AF

Comment: You're setting the view property of a UIViewController to another UIViewController? That's...not right. The view property should represent a UIViewController's view.

Comment: Why its wrong? I don want to create the view controller then add a new view to it and i wont use its existing one anymore!it will be a waste of memory. so i am resetting it with another view at runtime.

Comment: Are you sure the delay time you are setting is enough, and the operation wont exceed the delay you set?

Comment: Another view (UIView) is fine - but you shouldn't assign a UIViewController to the view property (which is how I understood your original post). It sounds as if you're trying to implement "The user taps an item in VC1, and should get VC2 for detail view". That's better handled with a UINavigationController than hacking the self.view property.Wasting memory is only a problem if you don't give it back when it's needed, which you can handle in viewDidUnload or didReceiveMemoryWarning

Comment: This should really be split into a separate question and answer. I say this partly because this is how SO works and partly because while I think you have a valid question I'm not convinced about your solution.

Comment: Ok i will explain what i am doing: my application loads VC1, in viewDidLoad i check for some preferences, if i get what i am after i do not need the "view" of VC1 any more, so  create another view controller and do this: [vc1 setView vc2.view]. Thats what i meant by setting. If i do not find the preference i am after i keep the loading do its usual business. In both situations now i can get viewDidAppear and the others called.

Answer (score 1):

Why would you go to all this bother just to save the memory of a UIViewController?

sizeof(UIViewController) gives 132 bytes. Even knowing that a view controller will create a fair few support objects so it's going to take up more memory than that this is a fantastic example of premature optimization.

I'd give it a fair chance that the code solution you have gone for will :

(a) leak memory in edge cases
(b) fail on further updates to iOS
(c) be a nightmare to debug by any coder other than yourself
(d) be a nightmare to debug by yourself in more than a few weeks

Why not just write your app using the frameworks provided and profile it - if this tiny amount of memory is causing you problems the fine, implement your solution. If not, leave well alone.